# Stop accepting GET request in spring j_acegi_security_check

Tags: spring, security, authentication, spring-security

I am using  `j_acegi_security_check` to login into the `Spring` web application but because it is accepting `GET` parameters, too, this means that I'm able to login into the application with

```
<https://localhost:8080/webapp/j_acegi_security_check?j_username=***&j_password=***&loginButton=Login>
```

I want to avoid this. It should accept only `POST` requests. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default spring security 3.x does only accept `POST` Requests for the login.

But you can controll this behaviour with the `postOnly` parameter of `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

(but as I said before, the default of `postOnly` is true)

---

But maybe the main problem is that you use an old spring acegi security and not the actual spring security 3.x.  It this is the case, than the statement above is my not true. So I strongly recommend to update!

In case of Spring ACEGI 1.0.x

Try to override the `attemptAuthentication` method in `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` with something like this:

```
if (request.getMethod().equals("POST"))
   return super.attemptAuthentication(request);
else
   throw new AuthenticationServiceException("service accept only http post");
```

*see the comments: overriding `onPreAuthentication()` seams also to be a good way*

Comment: Thanks for replying Ralph...in my present application i am using 1.0.5 version and Do you have any idea how to make it 'PostOnly' in that version security i don't have privileges to update the jars..

Comment: Have a look in the code, and search for the Filter (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter -- in 1.0.5 it has at least an other package, maybe an other name) that is responsible for Authentication. If it does not have this parameter, you need to subclass the Filter and add something like `if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) throw  new AuthenticationServiceException("not a POST");`

Comment: i am using this **org.acegisecurity.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter** filter and i found one class **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken** Class in **acegi_security package** which is similar to the name of the class which you provided above, So which class I should extend??

Comment: I do not want to be impolite, but do you have had a look hat this classes, did you read its java doc, did you TRYED to understand what they do? -- I hope so, if not I would be very sad that I told you that it is `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` override `attemptAuthentication` method like this `if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) return super.attemptAuthentication(request); else throw new AuthenticationServiceException("service accept only http post");`

Comment: I extended the **AuthenticationProcessingFilter** overrided **onPreAuthentication()** method and now it is working fine. Thanks for the support Ralph..:)

Comment: `onPreAuthentication()` sounds even better than `attemptAuthentication`